# Converting media files with VLC

Tags: vlc-media-player

i saw [How to convert media using VLC?](https://superuser.com/questions/28333/how-to-convert-media-using-vlc), but it seems that VLC will create a .ps file and when i rename the extension to mp3 (the format i told it to use) i can get it to play in VLC but not in another player eg. quicktime

also i cant seem to get it to convert many files at once?

Comment: I have always had problems trying to convert videos with VLC. So much so that I don't bother any more and use Handbrake or ffmpeg instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you had a look at the Videolan [Wiki tutorial](http://wiki.videolan.org/Transcode)?